# Is there a way to split the variable in different columns

Tags: split, hive, multiple-columns

Need help to split the variable in different columns.

The variable has 3 inputs separated by the symbol pipe '|'

The size of the input varies.

```
Using query : split(x, '|') [0] as abc, split(x, '|') [1] as bcd,

Input field x = 234324234|4873264962 


Required output:
    column 1: abc 234324234 
    column 2: bcd 4873264962
```

Answer (score 1):

InputField x: 234324234|4873264962

select split(x, '\\|') [0] as col1, split(x, '\\|') [1] as col2, split(x, '\\|') [2] as col3 from table.

col1               col2                  col3
234324234         4873264962               NULL